# Center of second animation not using new position

Tags: ios, animation, transform, frame

I am having an issue with running two animations in iOS. First i am trying to move the image from the bottom of the screen to the top by changing frame in the first animation set, then on completion i am trying to extend the length of the object by transforming the scale. But for some reason once the first animation is finished the object goes back to the original place at the bottom of the screen and the growing transformation happens off the screen. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help, here is my code:

```
CGRect fullview = CGRectMake(59, 102, 650, 150);
CGRect iconView = CGRectMake(59, 102, 290, 150);
CGRect textView = CGRectMake(349, 102, 360, 150);

[_profileBtn setEnabled:FALSE];
[_profileBtn setHidden:TRUE];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{  // animate the following:

    _profileIcon.frame = iconView; // move to new location
    _profileText.frame = textView; // move to new location
    _profileBackground.frame =fullview;

}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{  // animate the following:           
        _profileBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 5.64);
    }];


}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) for the UIView transform property. Specifically, what happens to the object's frame if you adjust the transform. I think instead of performing the second animation on the UIView's transform, you should apply it to the scale of its layer's transform.

Comment: after looking at the documentation i still don't know if i get it. Would you mind giving me an example of what you are talking about in code?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a solution that was close to what i wanted. This will do the translation and the movement at the same time:

```
    CGRect iconView = CGRectMake(59, 102, 290, 150);
    CGRect textView = CGRectMake(349, 102, 360, 150);
    _profileIcon.frame = iconView; // move to new location
    _profileText.frame = textView; // move to new location
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 5.00);
    CGRect fullview = CGRectMake(59, 40, 650, 150);
    _profileBackground.frame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(fullview,scale);
```